# Installer warnings about CoreAnimation and NSImage

Tags: macos, cocoa, installation

During app installation I get next warnings in console: 

`Installer[some-integer] CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
Installer[some-integer] *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.`
 
Please, point we what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> Installer[some-integer] CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with
>   uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment
>   to log backtraces. Installer[some-integer] ***

Your Installer is using `CATransaction` on secondary thread.
Use `CATransaction` on main thread.

> WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in
>   MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage
>   drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.

Your Installer is using deprecated API.
Use `[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:]`

Comment: No, `Installer` it is a installer for my application. It is not part of program itself.

Comment: then you can not fix this.